# While using <Client> TwiML the call always fails, there's no bug in the debugger and Client is active

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

I am trying to use Twilio Javascript Client to connect Incoming Calls to my Browser using WebRTC. The client is up and in ready state - with a proper capability token.

On the other hand, when I try to dial an outbound call with a TwiML script (to reply to an incoming call) the Outbound Call fails with a "failed" status and no additional information.

I have tried debugging the client, to see if the call is even landing to the Browser - but haven't had any success.

```
val say = Say
                .Builder("Welcome, please wait will call is connected")
                .language(Say.Language.EN_IN)
                .build()

        val client = Client.Builder("devansh.jain").build()
        val dial = Dial.Builder().client(client).build()
        val voiceResponse = VoiceResponse
                .Builder()
                .say(say)
                .dial(dial)
                .build()

        return voiceResponse.toXml()
```

The call is supposed to be connected to the browser. But the same is not happening. I am in `India` and the client is connected to the `Singapore` Region

Comment: I added debugger mode to the Client and got the following error.
`
{code: 31100, message: "Invalid application SID", twilioError: Error
    at new ConnectionError (http://localhost:7060/static/js/bundle.js:174033:32)
    at PStre…}
`

Where does Application SID go?

Comment: The application SID should be set in the access token. Can you share the code for that?

Answer (score 0):

I added Outgoing Scope with the IncomingScope in the client and it started working.

```
val incomingScope = IncomingClientScope(agentId)
val outboundScope = OutgoingClientScope.Builder(TWIML_APP_SID).build()
return capabilityBuilder
    .scopes(listOf(incomingScope, outboundScope))
    .build()
    .toJwt()
```